# Why do i keep getting the same error in using hibernate :ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I just want to show a list of bank transaction. I tested the query in oracle and it works:
`select bankDate, bankName from Bank where bankDate = '161222' group by bankDate, bankName`
i also tried to use count to show the amount of the transaction that made on that day and it also works. `select bankDate, bankName, count(bankName) as amount from Bank where bankDate = '161222' group by bankDate, bankName`

but somehow when i use the query:

```
public List<Bank> listBank() {
       List<Bank> list = (List<Bank>) getHibernateTemplate().find(
               "from Bank  where bankDate = '161222'" ); 
   return list;
   }
```

to my java project it went error like,

```
Hibernate: select bank0_.ID as ID0_, bank0_.BANKDATE as TRX2_0_, bank0_.BANKNAME as CARD3_0_ from mydb.mytable bank0_ where bank0_.BANKDATE='161222' group by bank0_.BANKDATE , bank0_.BANKNAME
Feb 05, 2020 11:56:12 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 979, SQLState: 42000
Feb 05, 2020 11:56:12 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:630)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:913)
    at com.jalin.bank.dao.impl.BankDaoImpl.listBank(BankDaoImpl.java:44)
    at com.jalin.bank.bo.impl.BankBoImpl.listBank(BankBoImpl.java:41)
    at com.jalin.common.App.main(App.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 15 more
```

i tried to use some of the example that are on internet, but it just wont work with me.. 
i also tried to use `<property ... formula="count(bankName)"></property>` for count, but it still won't do me any favor.

if someone can help me to work with hibernate are very welcome, i'm not really familiar with this. because i'm very new with spring mvc+maven+hibernate.

Comment: `from Bank  where bankDate = '161222'` is a `select * from ... group by`!! So it select not only `bankDate, bankName`. But I do not understand where the `group by` comes from in your query.

Comment: Not an expert in this field but the error reads like your query is malformed. I see an extra blank space between "Bank" and "where" in your query: "from Bank  where bankDate = '161222'". Maybe that's the problem already.

Comment: @palme An extra blank will not cause such issue

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation :

You are fetching two things in the query you are running manually whereas the one hibernate runs it is fetching three things. The error is because you need to group on all the columns that you use in select clause

ORA-00979 occurs when the GROUP BY clause does not contain all the expressions in the SELECT clause. Any SELECT expression that is not included in the GROUP function must be listed in the GROUP BY clause. These are AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, and VARIANCE. You may have also tried to execute a SELECT statement that contains a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `select bankDate, bankName, count(bankName) as amount from Bank where bankDate = '161222' group by bankDate, bankName`. The group by includes the 2 columns that need to be grouped. Don't group on `AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, and VARIANCE`